# Connect To a Bonjour Service with IP address

Tags: ios, objective-c, bonjour, nsnetservice

While I know Bonjour is used so that we don't get our hands messy with IPAddresses, but I need to write an app that can "manually add a new service by specifying the IPAddress".

According to the docs, one can do that by creating a connection by name (where the name is now the ipaddress) [Reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Networking/Conceptual/NSNetServiceProgGuide/Articles/ResolvingServices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001078-SW7 ]

```cs
 - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{

    switch (buttonIndex) {
        case 0:
            //Cancel
            break;
        case 1:
            //OK
            NSLog(@"%@",[[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0] text]);
            [self searchServiceOfType:SERVICE_TYPE inDomain:@"" withName:[[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0] text]];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    }


-(void)searchServiceOfType:(NSString *)serviceType inDomain:(NSString *)domain withName:(NSString*)serviceName{

    NSNetService *service;
    service = [[NSNetService alloc] initWithDomain:domain
                                              type:serviceType
                                              name:serviceName];
    [service setDelegate:self];
    [service stop];
    [service resolveWithTimeout:5.0];
}
```

The service doesn't resolve with errordict

```
Printing description of errorDict:

{
    NSNetServicesErrorCode = "-72004";
    NSNetServicesErrorDomain = 10;
}
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: Bonjour need for finding IP addresses. If you know IP address, then you don't need Bonjour.

Answer (score 0):

Error code `-72004` is `NSNetServicesBadArgumentError`.
According to the documentation of

```
- (id)initWithDomain:(NSString *)domain type:(NSString *)type name:(NSString *)name
```

you should use `@"local."` (and not `@""`) for the local domain.

Comment: Tried that. This time the connection times out. But the service very much exists.

Comment: @user1349663: Did you check with the "dns-sd" command line tool if the service is registered correctly? For example `dns-sd -B _http._tcp local.`

Comment: ok, did this. It lists my service with the "local." domain. Same credentials that I used to search for the service.

Comment: Urgh.. sorry, that was commented out. Its calls resolveWithTimeout. I'll update the question.